# Ignoring a single file when using include_directories with CMake

Tags: cmake

is there anyway to tell CMake to ignore one specific header file when using `include_directories` ?

Since the directories are not expanded into single files I can't just `list(REMOVE_ITEM ..)` the file out.

cheers Daniel

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to ignore a header file (if so, in what sense?) or do you want to leave out a directory from an include_directories call? I don't know how you would ignore a single file, but I do know how to delete files...

Comment: I have a directory that is shared between two projects. For certain reasons I want one of the projects to include everything but three specific header files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An include_directories call in CMakeLists does not result in a list of all available header-files. It simply passes those directories directly to the compiler as a search-dir for your "#include <...>" E.g. look at the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) for the "-I" option of GCC 4.6.

In addition: I am not sure why you would want to exclude a single file. Very often you can work around a problematic header file, by creating your own header-file in your own project which includes everything except that single-file...

If you really, really want something like this and you insist on solving it with CMake, you will probably end up with [file-globing](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afile) all header-files, copying (without that one file of course) them manually to a new include-dir and then include that new dir.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion Andre, I did the file-globing part already but didn't come up with the idea to move the files temporarily. However, given that you said manually I assume there is no mechanism in CMake that can do this for me. Thanks, anyway..